# Tool for diagnosis/proof of network connectivity issues

Tags: networking, ssh

I am in a shared workspace and am trying to communicate the issues I am having with the internet performance to the workspace provider. The main issue I have other than slowness is momentary connectivity loss. For instance, when I am connected to a server via ssh every 10 seconds the connection will freeze for a second or two (it will not drop entirely). This does not happen to me anywhere else...Is there some tool I can use that could monitor the connection and shed light on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Start with good ol fashioned ping.  From a windows machine, open a command prompt and run:

```
ping -n 100 <some external address>
```

Once it ends, you'll have a %loss.  If you are losing more than 2-3%, I would personally complain.  Also look at the average times.  On a decent internet connection, you should be able to ping something like yahoo.com or google.com and get response times of 10-50ms.  If you're getting response times 100+ms, then you're having pretty bad network performance.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I had tried this already, but did again, showing no packet loss and normal response times

Comment: Also consider ```mtr``` which can run in a terminal window and will show you the traceroute between you and the destination along with ping / packet loss numbers for each hop.

Comment: An alternate one-liner for a bash shell to continually measure packet loss is ```while true ; do ping -c 100 <ipaddress> | grep 'packet loss' ; done```, note that whether to use ```-n <count>``` or ```-c <count>``` depends on which fork of ```ping``` you are using.  The default for ping is 1 second between packets.

Answer (score 0):

For the ping test, i'd use PingPlotter, they have a free version that can run long term and graph your performance.  However, if you want true results then i'd say run a network analyzer tool like OpsView (they also have a free version)  this will give you alot more data than just ping.  Sometimes ping isn't enough.